# Leaflet : Firing an event when bounds change

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am using [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) to develop a new application. 
You can have an idea of the app [here](http://spo2tu.be:8002/).

I would like to fire an event whenever the bounds of the map change.
I looked at the doc but couldn't find anything related to that.

I have found the [getBounds()](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#bounds) method, and the list of possible [event methods](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#events), but nothing combining both.

The only other possibility I see to do that is to check for mouse drag and scroll events and check the bounds every time. 
But I was hoping there would be something better to do.

Would you have a better idea? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Map bounds are updated each time the map is moved (either by pan or zoom). So you can use moveend event for your purpose

```
map.on('moveend', function(e) {
   var bounds = map.getBounds();
});
```

Comment: Works perfectly, Thanks! FYI, your link is down on your profile. May be a .com or .fr missing?

Answer (score 2):

On react-leaflet, when setting maxBounds directly on the MapContainer component from leaflet, I had a warning `listener not found at MapContainer` with a stack trace.

If anybody runs on this issue from react-leaflet, I found a work around like this :

```
function MapEventHandlers() {
  const mapMoveEnd = useMapEvent('moveend', () => {
    mapMoveEnd.setMaxBounds([
      [51.234567, -5.67],
      [41.234567, 10.69],
    ])
  })
}

(...)

<MapContainer (...) >
  <MapEventHandlers />
  <TileLayer url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png" />
  (...)
</MapContainer>
```

Hope it helps :)