# Receiving data from .js in server.R shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, shiny-server

How would I receive data, created in a `.js` file in the `server.R` in shiny?

I am using the leaflat library and I need the extend the LatLngBounds of the current map view has. I need this variable in the `server.R` for furhter processing.

So i have

```
 mycode.js

//get bounds of extend of view
$(document).ready(function() { 

var myBounds = map.getBounds();
Shiny.onInputChange("bounds", myBounds);



});
```

which I include in the `ui.R` like

```
tags$body(tags$script(src="mycode.js"))
```

Thats how my `Server.R` looks like:

```
  myBoundsR <- reactive(
  as.numeric(input$bounds)
  print(input$bounds)
  )
```

However, how would I receive the data in the `server.R` file, coming from my `mycode.js`?

It feels like `Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler` is only to receive data in `.js` (or `.R`) while `session$sendCustomMessage` can only be used in the `.R` files? What would I use to send something from a `.js` file to the `server.R` file?!

Or can I simply use the variable `bound` as if I created it in the `server.R` file?!

Comment: You can try using `Shiny.onInputChange("var", data);` in your javscript, and `input$var` in your `server.R` to get the variable.

Comment: @NicE I would not have to take a detour of storing the variable in an non displayed div container and get it then?! Like suggested here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23715614/reading-javascript-variable-into-shiny-r-on-app-load Because when I write it like that `myBounds <- observe(as.numeric(input$bound))` it does not work. I tried to wrap it into the `reactive` function, that did not do the trick neither.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work. It's hard to help you out if you don't post more code/ an example that we can run.

Comment: @NicE Thats the error I get `Error in print(myBounds) : object 'myBounds' not found`. I think the `observe` function does not receive the variable from the `js file`? I updated my code up there.

Comment: need to be reactive if you want to store it in something, also you need to use `print(input$bound)` in the reactive expression. Unclear what `Number` is in your javascript, maybe try using `Shiny.onInputChange("bound", "something");` first to see if "something" gets printed in your R console. If it does, then the problem might be in your javascript.

Comment: @NicE Thanks for sticking with me! That `number` thing was a confusion on my side, I edited the code. However, it seems that the variable is not send to `server.R` because the `print(input$bounds)` function does not produce any output. When I include this peace console.log(myBounds);` into my `js file`, the desired output is printed into the console. What means. the `js` function works but the sending to `server.R` not.

Comment: @NicE in the console it says `TypeError: Shiny.onInputChange is not a function` in `myCode.js`

Comment: Ok not sure what's going on, anyway if you only want the bounds you can get them in `input$map_bounds` (assuming the id of your map is "map")

Comment: @NicE `map_bounds`? Where is that defined?

Comment: In the leaflet R package, see code [here](https://github.com/rstudio/leaflet/blob/4ef0023c9fefa00a64e382ccd77d34d1413c47dc/inst/legacy/www/binding.js). So in your shiny server.R, you can just get it that way, I posted an example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding what NicE wrote:

In the `file.js`

```
var myVariable = //do something
Shiny.onInputChange("variableNameToWriteInServer.R", myVariable)
```

In the `server.R`

```
observe({
# thats how you access the variable
    input$myVariable
#do something with the variable. To see if it worked something like
})
```

That should do the trick. If you use the `getBounds()` function keep that in mind [Leaflet : Firing an event when bounds change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24844969/leaflet-firing-an-event-when-bounds-change). Also, you might not receive any output since the `getBounds()` function does not return the bounds of the window when the window extend is not changed. But, its only execute once. In the article I linked is a solution for this.

For further undocumented communication in Shiny (server.R and ui.R) read here: https://ryouready.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/sending-data-from-client-to-server-and-back-using-shiny/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the map bounds, you can use `input$map_bounds`, if map is the id of your leaflet map.

Here is an example, (using the leaflet example code from the [tutorial](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html))

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

r_colors <- rgb(t(col2rgb(colors()) / 255))
names(r_colors) <- colors()

ui <- fluidPage(
  leafletOutput("map")
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  points <- cbind(rnorm(40) * 2 + 13, rnorm(40) + 48)

  observe({
    print(input$map_bounds)
  })
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>%  addTiles() 
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: You can find all the shiny bindings and input/output events [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/shiny.html), at the end of the page.