# Shiny - No side by side layout on mobile

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using a side-by-side layout to display multiple plots on the same row. However it looks bad on mobile. How can I keep the side by side layout on desktop, but 1 plot per row on mobile?

```R
fluidRow(
  splitLayout(cellWidths = c('49%', '49%'),
    plotlyOutput('pWaterLvl'),
    plotlyOutput('pHumidity')
  )
),
fluidRow(
  splitLayout(cellWidths = c('49%', '49%'),
    plotlyOutput('pWaterTemp'),
    plotlyOutput('pAirTemp')
  )
)
```

[image: The mobile layout]

Comment: You could get the user´s screen resolution via JS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250075/get-screen-resolution-from-javascript-in-r-shiny
and adapt the ui accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can let bootstrap grid system handle it.

```
fluidRow(
  column(6, plotlyOutput('pWaterLvl')),
  column(6, plotlyOutput('pHumidity')) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to control the grid sizes on multiple devices, you can use a combination of the width and class settings (width controls 'col-sm' by default).

This example puts the plots on top of each other on small screens, next to each other on medium screens, and makes the second plot slightly wider on large screens.

```
fluidRow(
  column(12, class = "col-md-6 col-lg-5", plotlyOutput('pWaterLvl')),
  column(12, class = "col-md-6 col-lg-7", plotlyOutput('pHumidity')) 
)
```