# Can Shiny recognise text selection with mouse (highlighted text)?

Tags: r, shiny

I need the user to assign text fragments to categories or "codes" in Shiny. Basically, I would like the user to highlight a text from an output (in the example below, from a `table` or `text` output), then press a button (`code`) and assign the selected text to an object within the app. In the app below, the selected text should be rendered as `output$selected_text`. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this, I suspect [JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17227070/can-i-get-highlighted-text-with-jquery) would be helpful.

```
library(shiny)

text1 <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec quam ut tortor interdum pulvinar id vitae magna. Curabitur commodo consequat arcu et lacinia. Proin at diam vitae lectus dignissim auctor nec dictum lectus. Fusce venenatis eros congue velit feugiat, ac aliquam ipsum gravida. Cras bibendum malesuada est in tempus. Suspendisse tincidunt, nisi non finibus consequat, ex nisl condimentum orci, et dignissim neque est vitae nulla." 
text2 <- "Aliquam ut purus neque. Maecenas justo orci, semper eget purus eu, aliquet molestie mi. Duis convallis ut erat at faucibus. Quisque malesuada ante elementum, tempor felis et, faucibus orci. Praesent iaculis nisi lorem, non faucibus neque suscipit eu. Ut porttitor risus eu convallis tristique. Integer ac mauris a ex maximus consequat eget non felis. Pellentesque quis sem aliquet, feugiat ligula vel, convallis sapien. Ut suscipit nulla leo"

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Text to code"),
           tags$h2("From table"),
           tableOutput("table"),
           tags$h2("From raw text"),
           verbatimTextOutput("text")
    ),
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Coding options"),
           actionButton("code1", "Assign selected text to Code1"),
           tags$h1("Code1 output"),
           verbatimTextOutput("selected_text")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(paragraph = 1:2, text = c(text1, text2))
  })

  output$text <- renderText(paste(text1, text2))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: A simplified way to achieve a similar effect would be to just have the user copy the selected text into a `textInput`, but I'm not sure if this is an option for you.

Comment: I did, @Marijn, but I would like to minimise the amount of work that the user has to carry out since a lot of this coding will be required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it can.
`javascript` is indeed useful for this, not sure if it's necessary, but it is certainly easier.

I based my answer on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5379408/1261281) to get the highlighted text in `js` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32187536/1261281) to send the data from `js` to `R`, so credit is to the original author.

Simple reproducible code first, then I'll explain what's going on:

#### server.R

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    output$results = renderPrint({
        input$mydata
    })

})
```

#### ui.R

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(

    # a div named mydiv
    div(id="mydiv", "SOME text here"),

    # a shiny element to display unformatted text
    verbatimTextOutput("results"),

    # javascript code to send data to shiny server
    tags$script('
                function getSelectionText() {
                    var text = "";
                    if (window.getSelection) {
                        text = window.getSelection().toString();
                    } else if (document.selection) {
                        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
                    }
                    return text;
                }

        document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
            var selection = getSelectionText();
            Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", selection);
        };
        ')
))
```

`Server.R` is simple enough that does not need explanation, we simply render the content of `input$mydata`.

The juice happens in `ui.R` where we have three elements:

- A `div` element (with `id='mydiv'`)
- A text output that render the result from `server.R`
- A script tag, that contains the `javascript` we need.

Inside the script tag, we first have a function that gets the selection. This is a copy of the `js` answer (with the exception that I got an error when the `js` contains `&&` logical operator, that somehow gets translated badly)

This function is called `onmouseup`, `onkeyup` and `onselectionchange`, and its result assigned to `selection`.

---

Finally *and probably the important bit*, the `js` function  `Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", selection)` assign the content of `js`'s `selection` variable to `mydata` `R`'s variable.

---

Hope this helps

Comment: What an amazing response. Thank you kind sir

Comment: that's great, can we restrict this so it only responds to selections made within a specific element like "mydiv"?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @GGamba, I could develop the following answer for my given example:

```
library(shiny)

text1 <- "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce nec quam ut tortor interdum pulvinar id vitae magna. Curabitur commodo consequat arcu et lacinia. Proin at diam vitae lectus dignissim auctor nec dictum lectus. Fusce venenatis eros congue velit feugiat, ac aliquam ipsum gravida. Cras bibendum malesuada est in tempus. Suspendisse tincidunt, nisi non finibus consequat, ex nisl condimentum orci, et dignissim neque est vitae nulla." 
text2 <- "Aliquam ut purus neque. Maecenas justo orci, semper eget purus eu, aliquet molestie mi. Duis convallis ut erat at faucibus. Quisque malesuada ante elementum, tempor felis et, faucibus orci. Praesent iaculis nisi lorem, non faucibus neque suscipit eu. Ut porttitor risus eu convallis tristique. Integer ac mauris a ex maximus consequat eget non felis. Pellentesque quis sem aliquet, feugiat ligula vel, convallis sapien. Ut suscipit nulla leo"
highlight <- '
                function getSelectionText() {
var text = "";
if (window.getSelection) {
text = window.getSelection().toString();
} else if (document.selection) {
text = document.selection.createRange().text;
}
return text;
}

document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
var selection = getSelectionText();
Shiny.onInputChange("mydata", selection);
};
'

coded_text <- character(0)

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  tags$script(highlight),
  fluidRow(
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Text to code"),
           tags$h2("From table"),
           tableOutput("table"),
           tags$h2("From raw text"),
           verbatimTextOutput("text")
    ),
    column(4,
           tags$h1("Coding options"),
           actionButton("code1", "Assign selected text to Code1"),
           tags$h1("Code1 output"),
           verbatimTextOutput("selected_text")
    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  output$table <- renderTable({
    data.frame(paragraph = 1:2, text = c(text1, text2))
  })

  output$text <- renderText(paste(text1, text2))

  coded <- eventReactive(input$code1, {
    coded_text <<- c(coded_text, input$mydata)
    coded_text
  })

  output$selected_text <- renderPrint({
    coded()
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi, this is really useful, thanks for sharing. Do you know how one would add a button to reset the selected text items ie if the user wishes to start all over again?

Comment: hi @tezzaaa i have the same question. were you able to figure out? my solution right now is to include a "reset" button that is an `observeEvent` and the action is to `session$reload()`. but i feel like this solution is a little "clunky"