# Converting Responsive Grid Layout to Plotly Dash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, plotly-dash, react-grid-layout

I'm a very active Dash user and I have started to find a lot of limitations in my Dash usage and I realized that the information/contents about how converting components to dash are absolutely limited, with outdated and very simple examples... And I do not have almost any knowledge in Javascript or React, I'm completely lost on how to convert a component.

I'm trying to convert the Responsive Grid Layout component from react.js to Plotly Dash but I don't know how should I deal with the properties in this case?
Link to the component:
https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout/blob/master/lib/ResponsiveReactGridLayout.jsx

As I'm not experienced with react.js I'm confused about what modifications should I do to be able to convert this component to Plotly Dash.

In the case of the component above, should I only declare the Properties on the Proptypes (as shown below) or do I need to do more modifications?

```
ResponsiveReactGridLayout.propTypes{
  //
  // Basic props
  //
  className: PropTypes.string,
  style: PropTypes.object,

  // This can be set explicitly. If it is not set, it will automatically
  // be set to the container width. Note that resizes will *not* cause this to adjust.
  // If you need that behavior, use WidthProvider.
  width: PropTypes.number,

  // If true, the container height swells and contracts to fit contents
  autoSize: PropTypes.bool,
  // # of cols.
  cols: PropTypes.number,

  // A selector that will not be draggable.
  draggableCancel: PropTypes.string,
  // A selector for the draggable handler
  draggableHandle: PropTypes.string,

  // Deprecated
  verticalCompact: function (props: Props) {
    if (
      props.verticalCompact === false &&
      process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production"
    ) {
      console.warn(
        // eslint-disable-line no-console
        "`verticalCompact` on <ReactGridLayout> is deprecated and will be removed soon. " +
          'Use `compactType`: "horizontal" | "vertical" | null.'
      );
    }
  },
  // Choose vertical or hotizontal compaction
  compactType: PropTypes.oneOf(["vertical", "horizontal"]),

  // layout is an array of object with the format:
  // {x: Number, y: Number, w: Number, h: Number, i: String}
  layout: function (props: Props) {
    var layout = props.layout;
    // I hope you're setting the data-grid property on the grid items
    if (layout === undefined) return;
    require("./utils").validateLayout(layout, "layout");
  },

  //
  // Grid Dimensions
  //

  // Margin between items [x, y] in px
  margin: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
  // Padding inside the container [x, y] in px
  containerPadding: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.number),
  // Rows have a static height, but you can change this based on breakpoints if you like
  rowHeight: PropTypes.number,
  // Default Infinity, but you can specify a max here if you like.
  // Note that this isn't fully fleshed out and won't error if you specify a layout that
  // extends beyond the row capacity. It will, however, not allow users to drag/resize
  // an item past the barrier. They can push items beyond the barrier, though.
  // Intentionally not documented for this reason.
  maxRows: PropTypes.number,

  //
  // Flags
  //
  isBounded: PropTypes.bool,
  isDraggable: PropTypes.bool,
  isResizable: PropTypes.bool,
  // If true, grid items won't change position when being dragged over.
  preventCollision: PropTypes.bool,
  // Use CSS transforms instead of top/left
  useCSSTransforms: PropTypes.bool,
  // parent layout transform scale
  transformScale: PropTypes.number,
  // If true, an external element can trigger onDrop callback with a specific grid position as a parameter
  isDroppable: PropTypes.bool,

  // Resize handle options
  resizeHandles: resizeHandlesType,
  resizeHandle: resizeHandleType,

  //
  // Callbacks
  //

  // Callback so you can save the layout. Calls after each drag & resize stops.
  onLayoutChange: PropTypes.func,

  // Calls when drag starts. Callback is of the signature (layout, oldItem, newItem, placeholder, e, ?node).
  // All callbacks below have the same signature. 'start' and 'stop' callbacks omit the 'placeholder'.
  onDragStart: PropTypes.func,
  // Calls on each drag movement.
  onDrag: PropTypes.func,
  // Calls when drag is complete.
  onDragStop: PropTypes.func,
  //Calls when resize starts.
  onResizeStart: PropTypes.func,
  // Calls when resize movement happens.
  onResize: PropTypes.func,
  // Calls when resize is complete.
  onResizeStop: PropTypes.func,
  // Calls when some element is dropped.
  onDrop: PropTypes.func,

  //
  // Other validations
  //

  droppingItem: PropTypes.shape({
    i: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    w: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    h: PropTypes.number.isRequired
  }),

  // Children must not have duplicate keys.
  children: function (props: Props, propName: string) {
    var children = props[propName];

    // Check children keys for duplicates. Throw if found.
    var keys = {};
    React.Children.forEach(children, function (child) {
      if (keys[child.key]) {
        throw new Error(
          'Duplicate child key "' +
            child.key +
            '" found! This will cause problems in ReactGridLayout.'
        );
      }
      keys[child.key] = true;
    });
  },

  // Optional ref for getting a reference for the wrapping div.
  innerRef: PropTypes.any
};
```

Any help or references are very welcome...

Regards,
Leonardo

Answer (score 3):

#### Implementing the custom component

If you just want to use components from a library with a package available through `npm` (like `react-grid-layout`), you don't need to re-implement the components in these libraries. You can simply install them with `npm` and use them in your custom component.

Example component using `ResponsiveGridLayout` (`src/lib/components/GridLayout.react.js`):

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import RGL, {WidthProvider} from 'react-grid-layout';
import '../../../node_modules/react-grid-layout/css/styles.css';
import '../../../node_modules/react-resizable/css/styles.css';

const ResponsiveGridLayout = WidthProvider(RGL);

export default class GridLayout extends Component {
    render() {
        const {id, setProps} = this.props;
        const layout = [
            {x: 0, y: 0, w: 3, h: 3, i: 'a'},
            {x: 0, y: 1, w: 3, h: 3, i: 'b'},
        ];

        return (
            <div id={id}>
                <ResponsiveGridLayout rowHeight={30}>
                    {layout.map((item) => (
                        <div key={item.i} data-grid={item}>
                            <span>{item.i}</span>
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </ResponsiveGridLayout>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

GridLayout.defaultProps = {};

GridLayout.propTypes = {
    /**
     * The ID used to identify this component in Dash callbacks.
     */
    id: PropTypes.string,

    /**
     * Dash-assigned callback that should be called to report property changes
     * to Dash, to make them available for callbacks.
     */
    setProps: PropTypes.func,
};
```

#### Environment setup (Skip if you've already done this)

To create and edit your custom component you need to have followed the instructions to setup the [cookiecutter dash-component-boilerplate](https://dash.plotly.com/react-for-python-developers).

But to re-iterate what is said in a couple of bullet points, you need to:

- Install `cookiecutter`: `pip install cookiecutter`
- Run cookiecutter `https://github.com/plotly/dash-component-boilerplate.git`. This will generate the environment where you can create your custom components.
- After filling in the name you want your custom component to have you change directory into the directory generated based on the name you provided. I have chosen the name `grid_layout`, your structure will be different if you choose different values after being prompted by `cookiecutter`.
- At this point you need to install the needed python dependencies by running `pip install -r requirements.txt`. You can now also install `react-grid-layout` using `npm i react-grid-layout`.

#### Basic usage

When everything is installed we can edit the custom component inside the `src/lib/components` directory. When we've made some change (replaced the example code with the code listed above) and we are satisfied we can run `npm run build` to persist the changes.

After this you can run `python usage.py` and your dash app using your custom component will be run.

`usage.py` is a regular `Dash` application that imports the component that is generated from the `react` component after the build process and can look something like this:

```
import grid_layout
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([grid_layout.GridLayout(id="grid-layout")])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

You can also edit this as you like.

Comment: Hey Bas, thank you very much for your answer, matte! 
So, based on your example, can I assume that I do not need to declare all the component features? I mean, only the setProps is enough? 
Also, on another component that I have as a reference, I note that the creator needed to create the functions to change the states and so on.... You can see what I'm mentioning here: https://github.com/AlgorithmHub/dash-responsive-grid-layout/blob/master/src/lib/components/ResponsiveGridLayout.react.js; Note that there are onLayoutChange, on BreakpointChange, and other settings.

Comment: Yes the `react-grid-layout` library can handle the definition of its own components and you can use them as you like. In general I would include `setProps` and `id` for your custom components. That link is a good example of a possible implementation using `react-grid-layout`, but it doesn't need to be your implementation necessarily. If you feel like you don't need to handle the `onChangeLayout` for your use-case or you want to handle it differently you can do so. If you do want to handle props like  `onChangeLayout` I think your link provides a good way to go about handling it.