# Can we use plotly dash app to be used within a react app?

Tags: python, reactjs, plotly-dash

I am new to react and dash. I have developed a dash application where there are dynamic operations and graphs been plotted. Now, the organization requirement is I need to use react in order to maintain consistency with other applications. Is there any way I can utilize my dash application and convert it or leverage it as a react app without having to rewrite the whole application in react again?

Comment: You can create custom dash components using React. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66141429/9098350)

Comment: Thank you @BasvanderLinden. So, it would be a react app with embedded dash, is it? (with a node backend)?

Comment: Yes that’s possible. As far as structure goes I would keep things separate. So you have one folder that generates custom dash components from React code, your actual frontend application that uses the custom components and finally your node backend.

Comment: @Jayashri were you able to use your developed dash app and connect it to React?  Or did you have to migrate code?