# How can I integrate Plotly Dash into a React app?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, plotly, plotly-dash

I built apps in Dash, but the team only wants everything in React.

Is there a way to integrate my Dash app into the React app so they can be in the same place?

Also, I realized that Dash is built upon React. Can I get the generated React JavaScript source code as well?

Comment: You can do it the other way around. You can create a custom dash component library which converts react components to dash components you can integrate in your dash app. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66141429/9098350).